# How can I run my own apache module on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: apache2, apache2-module, ubuntu-10.10

I want to play with my own apache module (in C or C++, maybe python), but I cannot find any solution for it. I missing apache header files (I have no httpd folder in /etc/apache2/ which contain includes), even if I copy that I missing some header files. Where can I find some good tutor for new apache (not the oldone 1.3). Maybe you can tell me some important things, which I have to cover in my mind to write my own apache module.

Answer (score 0):

Start by installing the apache2-dev virtual package (assuming you want to use the system-provided apache, as it sounds is the case).

Comment: Yes it is system-provided apache and I've just installed dev package. I have httpd folder and lot of includes divided into two folders: /etc/apache2/httpd/include/ and /etc/apache2/httpd/srclib/apr/include/. Tell that I have my module in first_module.c. What next?

Comment: @sennin: I don't know; I see one tutorial at http://threebit.net/tutorials/apache2_modules/tut1/tutorial1.html; maybe give it a try.

Comment: I've already done this tutorial, but I stopped at the end, because of lacking header files, and compilling problems:/ I think it could be too old now.